# Fetch Microsoft Exchange / Outlook profile photo using Python

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, gravatar, avatar

Is it possible to fetch user profile photo on an MS Exchange network using Python?

Currently users signup with their company domain, and I'd like to fetch their profile photo automatically.  Maybe something similar to gravatar, but for Microsoft networks?

Answer (score 0):

The data is actually stored in the Active Directory. I don't remember the AD attribute off the top of my head, but on the MAPI level, the property can be retrieved from the PR_EMS_AB_THUMBNAIL_PHOTO (PidTagThumbnailPhone) property.